# Django alter admin save to alter another table field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am creating a django site that includes a rudimentary inventory system. Which includes the following models

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    # Fields
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

class Transfer(models.Model):
    # Fields
    location1 = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location1')
    location2 = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location2')
    date_transferred = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

class TransferLine(models.Model):
    # Choice set
    direction_set = (
        ('1TO2', 'From 1 to 2'),
        ('2TO1', 'From 2 to 1')
    )

    # Fields
    transfer = models.ForeignKey(Transfer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    transfer_direction = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=direction_set, default='1TO2')
```

When I create a new transfer I want to be able to automatically deduct and add the product in the TransferLine from the quantities in the Stock model.

I have figured out how to override the save_model method in the admin.py file for the TransferAdmin class, but I cannot figure out how to access the Stock model from within the SaleAdmin class.

Is this something that can be done in the admin? Will I have to create my own form? I really wanted to do this from admin because inlinetabular is really easy to do within admin compared to within a custom built form. (At least from what I can find.)

Any help on this would be appreciated.

To help clarify, let's say that my database has the following for Stock:

```
|id |loc_id|prod_id|qty|
|:-:|:----:|:-----:|:-:|
|1  |1     |1      |6  |
|1  |2     |1      |6  |
```

Then I complete the form for a transaction that will transfer 3 of product 1 from location 1 to location 2. I want to update the Stock table to the following once the transaction form is saved.

```
|id |loc_id|prod_id|qty|
|:-:|:----:|:-----:|:-:|
|1  |1     |1      |3  |
|1  |2     |1      |9  |
```

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: Django signals might be a help to do this task. So the concept is that, in your signals.py, you'll have to add a function that involves post_save.

Comment: @jerome_mjt: I didn't think that you could do this with signals. The Django documentation for the model post-save signal states, "One should not query/modify other records in the database as the database might not be in a consistent state yet." Did  I misunderstand that sentence?

Comment: Oh yeah. You can just override the save method of the stock model and put the logic inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    # Fields
    location1 = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location1')
    location2 = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='location2')
    date_transferred = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = False
        if not self.id:
            created = True
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created:
            # will execute after the creation
            transfer_line = TransferLine.objects.create(transfer=self)  # self = created tranfer
```

Comment: How does this give me access to the Stock model? I am not seeing it.

Comment: transfer_line.product.stock_set.all()